# sqlite3 with Swift: specific path not working

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have been trying to set a specific path for my SQLite Database, but it ain't working, be it relative or absolute, except with "file:myDB"

Any idea why?

```
func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer? {

var db: OpaquePointer?
let path = "file:///Users/me/Desktop/myDB.db"
if sqlite3_open_v2(path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_URI | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    print("successfully opened connection to database at \(path)")
    return db
}
else {
    print("Unable to open database.")
    sqlite3_close(db)
}

}
let db = openDatabase()
```

Comment: Not all versions of SQLite are compiled with URI support. You might want to check that, and capture the return code of `sqlite3_open()` to see if it gives any more information.

Comment: Also, apps are now sandboxed, so you can’t just open files wherever you want. If it’s out of the sandbox, you have to request permission from the user. The question is whether you really need the database in a non-sandboxed folder or whether you might be equally happy creating the database in the “application support” directory, for example, which wouldn’t require user approval.

Comment: You also might want to call `sqlite3_errmsg` to get a meaningful error message in your `else` clause.

Comment: thanks. I forgot about this sandboxing thing ... been inactive for too long in this field. I will check!